# AngularJS: How to hide menu when pressing a button

Tags: angularjs

I have a button that is used to toggle a menu, but that menu should also have a button inside used to hide it.

I really hope that is an easy issue to solve because I don't have experience with AngularJS...

Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>
<div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed">
  <ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>
  <button class="hide-menu">
    Close menu
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, It's easy add click event to button `ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"`

finally code is

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>
<div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed">
  <ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>
  <button class="hide-menu" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
    Close menu
  </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To toggle the hide the menu or for toggle add this to your Menu Button.

```
<button class="hide-menu"   ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
    Close menu
  </button>
```

ThankYou. I hope this was HelpFul.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line

`ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"`

```
<button class="hide-menu"  ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
    Close menu
  </button>
```